# how to add comma before et al in the reference?

Tags: bibtex

```
@ARTICLE{Guyatt2007,
  author = {G. H. Guyatt and P. J. Devereaux and J. Lexchin
            and S. B. Stone and A. Yalnizyan and D. Himmelstein
            and S. Woolhandler and Q. Zhou and L. J. Goldsmith
            and D. J. Cook and T. Haines and C. Lacchetti and J. N. Lavis
            and T. Sullivan and E. Mills and S. Kraus and N. Bhatnagar},
  title = {A systematic review of studies comparing health outcomes in
           {C}anada and the {U}nited {S}tates},
  journal = {Open Med},
  year = {2007},
  volume = {\textbf{1}},
  pages = {27--36}
}
```

From this I get:

> Guyatt GH, Devereaux PJ, Lexchin J et al. A systematic review of studies comparing health outcomes in Canada and the United States. Open Med 2007; 1: 27–36.

But I need:

> Guyatt GH, Devereaux PJ, Lexchin J, et al. A systematic review of studies comparing health outcomes in Canada and the United States. Open Med 2007; 1: 27–36.

Comment: The answer to this question will crucially depend on the bibliography and citation package you use (you tagged this question with `biblatex`, but do you really use `biblatex` or do you use `natbib`, `cite`, `jurabib`, ...) as well as on the particular style you use (`\bibliographystyle{...}`/`style=...`). Please tell us about these things in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: I use \bibliographystyle{SageV} in the template of this journal https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/asi/manuscript-submission-guidelines#PreparingYourManuscript

Comment: Please share a fully working minimal example (see the two links) above.

Comment: You should also double check  if you really need that comma or if you just misread the author guidelines. Surely the publisher's `.bst` file should provide the correct output.  If you plan to submit to a SAGEpub outlet and their template does not meet their submission guidelines you should tell them. If you are not submitting to them you should probably not be using their `.bst` files.

Answer (score 2):

Let me begin by echoing @moewe's comment that if some journal is making you use the `sageV` bibliography style, you shouldn't have to perform any additional bibliography-related tweaking and fine tuning of the formatted bibliographic entries. In particular, you shouldn't have to enter a comma before the `et al` string.

However, if you believe that you really have to do this, I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `sageV.bst` and make a copy. Call the copy, say, `sageV-extra-commas.bst`.
- Open the file `sageV-extra-commas.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the bst file, find all 3 instances of the string `" " * bbl.etal`. (In my copy of the file, these strings may be found on lines 453, 828, and 836.)
- Replace all instances of this string with `", " * bbl.etal`. Note the comma.
- Save the file `sageV-extra-commas.bst` either in the directory where you main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{sageV}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{sageV-extra-commas}
  ```
- Finally, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: Of course changing the `.bst` file locally won't do any good for the journal submission if the guidelines at https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/asi/manuscript-submission-guidelines#PreparingYourManuscript are followed, where it is suggested that the `.bib` file be uploaded and not the `.bbl`.

Comment: @moewe - I was assuming -- quite possibly without proper support! -- that the OP wishes to modify the workings of the bst file for reasons that aren't actually related to submitting a manuscript and its components (such as the bib file) to a journal for eventual publication...